# How to refresh a FilteredItemsSelectionDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` shose underlying *data model* may change while the dialog is open. If there are structural changes, i.e. elements are added or removed, I am unable to tell the dialog to update its filtered list.

I tried calling `refresh()` and `reloadCache()` and also `scheduleRefresh()` (which essentially runs `reloadCache()` in a Job), but all methods re-use the elements that were initially added to the content provider.

What I think would solve the problem is a way to reset the content provider and have it call `fillContentProvider()` again. Then I could re-populate the content provider with the current state of the model. While preserving the current filter and selection, of course.

[BEGIN EDIT]

Based on Greg's answer here is what I also tried:

```java
ItemsFilter overrideFilter;

@Override
protected ItemsFilter createFilter() {  
  if( overrideFilter != null ) {
    return overrideFilter;
  }
  return new LaunchConfigItemsFilter();
}

public void forceRefresh() {
  overrideFilter = new ItemsFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean matchItem( Object item ) {
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConsistentItem( Object item ) {
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equalsFilter( ItemsFilter filter ) {
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSubFilter( ItemsFilter filter ) {
      return false;
    }
  };
  applyFilter();
  overrideFilter = null;
  applyFilter();
}
```

`forceRefresh()` is called whenever the model structure changes. The intention is to first call `applyFilter()` with a filter that will never match the existing one and thus triggers `fillContentProider()` and then again call `applyFilter()` with the current filter to restore the elements that match.

But when an element is added and another is removed, the outcome is that the deleted element is still visible.

What I also tried is to let `createFilter()` return `null` for the first call to `applyFilter()`. This again leaves the deleted element visible.

Irrespective of whether a fitler was set or not before the elments were added and removed, at its best, the list is in a meaningful state only after I cleared and (re-)entered a filter.

[END EDIT]

To give some context, the dialog in question lists launch configurations, the code can be found here: 
https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/blob/master/com.codeaffine.extras.launch/src/com/codeaffine/extras/launch/internal/dialog/LaunchSelectionDialog.java

Does anyone know a way to force the `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` to reset and refill its content provider?

Answer (score 2):

If I read the code correctly calling `applyFilter` will rerun all the code to fill the table including calling `fillContentProvider`.

When checking if it needs to do anything `applyFilter` calls `createFilter`, this must return a filter and the filter's `ItemsFilter.equalsFilter` method must return false when compared with the previous filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been fiddling around with `applyFilter` already. I've edited the question to include with what I came up with.

Comment: I am giving up here. If the list is unfiltered (most difficult case) it would be necessary to call `applyFilter()` with a non-empty dummy filter and wait for the two Jobs that it schedules (this is crucial to bring things into the right state for the next step), then call `applyFilter()` again with the real (empty) filter. That's one quirk too much for my taste. Again, thanks for your help.